# CComboBox, more than 65535 items

Tags: ccombobox

So I created a CComboBox.  There are more than 65535 items.  When I drag the scroll bar past item number 65535, it shows items earlier in the box.  If I let go of the the scrollbar, it jumps up.  Other things work, page up, page down, hitting the arrow to scroll down, it's just when I drag the scroll bar when I have that problem.

Comment: I'm going to guess that a CComboBox isn't the right tool for this job, with 65k items.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs9a0bwf.aspx

The combo box returns an `int` value, which is limited range of `0` to `65535` -- tells us how much capacity that container can hold.

You've hit an integer overflow issue and there isn't anything you can do except have less data or change tools.